# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script　というメールが届く

Tags: google-apps-script

フォームから申請していただき、スプレッドシートにデータがたまるように設定しているのですが、Summary of failures for Google Apps Script　というメールが2件届きました。スプレッドシートにはデータがたまっているのですが、なぜこのようなメールが届くのでしょうか？